# How do I assign to a vertex group with geometry nodes?

Tags: vertex-groups, geometry-nodes, experimental-features

I'm working in Blender 2.93 Alpha (more details if needed), and I'm looking for a way to apply a solidify modifier to only a specific vertex group. However, I can't figure out how to assign pieces of my geometry node group to the vertex group.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood the question, but as I understand it you could use an attribute mix node with the factor being the vertex group, and the inputs being the different "branches" of the node network you want applying.[image: Attribute mix example] In this example I mix two sets of points, one from a scaled up sphere and one from the original vertex position. For the solidify modifier you can just use the vertex group input, with a group. Sorry if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Actually, I was asking more of something like this:

I have an object which is created entirely with primitives and transformations using geometry nodes. I need a way to solidify one of these objects, without doing it to the rest of the geometry. How do I assign vertexes to a vertex group using geometry nodes?